# ¿Para qué sirve <> en la definición de clases abstractas?

Tags: java

He estado mirando por algunas webs cómo funcionan las clases abstractas, y creo que lo he entendido bien, pero he visto un ejemplo donde no entiendo una parte, y no sé cómo buscarlo para acceder a algún tutorial donde lo explique.

Se trata de cuando al crear una clase abstracta se ponen `<>` después del nombre de la clase:

```java
public abstract class Coche <Data>
```

¿Para qué sirve `<>`?

Y luego el método abstracto tiene también el `<>`:

```java
abstract <data> double calcularDistanciaPorRecorrer(double VelocidadMedia);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, esto se debe a que esa clase abstracta esta parametrizada por un tipo determinado de objetos .

Te paso una página donde encontrarás información sobre esto.

http://jonsegador.com/2012/10/clases-y-tipos-genericos-en-java/

Comment: Gracias todo aclarado

Answer (score 2):

Eso no tiene que ver con las clases abstractas, tiene que ver con los genéricos. Mira la [documentación de Java al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) y lo comprenderás. Las llaves sirven para que una parte del código no esté estrictamente tipada sino que pueda responder **genéricamente** a distintos tipos y poder reutilizar más el código. Los genéricos se declaran entre ángulos `<>`

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba totalmente confundido

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta entre `<>` es el tipo de objeto en el cual tu clase o método esta parametrizado. No es exclusivo de una clase o método abstracto.

Dentro de los contendores `<>` es definido el tipo de objeto:

`<miObjeto>`

O un tipo generico que puede ser:

- E – Element (usado bastante por Java Collections Framework)

  - K – Key
  - N - Number
  - T – Type
  - V – Value S,U,V etc. – usado para representar
    otros tipos.